# GridBagLayout Not Working when adding second element

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm just learning about `GridBagLayout`. When I add a `JTextField` to my layout, everything seems to disappear

```
//      final JTextField textField = new JTextField("textField");
//      addComponentToGridbag(textField, 0,0,1,1);

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        addComponentToGridbag(button, 1,0,1,1);
```

If I leave those first two lines commented out, I get this, which is OK except that there is no text field (of course):

[image]

But I want a text field to appear directly above the button, so I uncomment those two lines. And then I get this (notice how not only did my button disappear, but so did my top and bottom panels):

[image]

What is going on? How can I get a text field to appear without losing the other stuff? Thanks!

Here is the entire class:

```
public class GUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    private GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    private GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    private JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();

    public GUI() {

        makeMainFrame();
        makePanels();
        bodyLayout();

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Dashboard");
        topPanel.add(title);

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        bottomPanel.add(btnExit);
    }

    private void bodyLayout() {

        centerPanel.setLayout(layout);

        final JTextField textField = new JTextField("textField");
        addComponentToGridbag(textField, 0,0,1,1);

        JButton btnFetchMetaData = new JButton("Button");
        addComponentToGridbag(btnFetchMetaData, 1,0,1,1);
    }

    private void addComponentToGridbag(Component component, int row, int column, int width, int height) {
        constraints.gridx = column;
        constraints.gridy = row;
        constraints.gridwidth = width;
        constraints.gridheight = height;
        layout.setConstraints(component, constraints);
        centerPanel.add(component);
    }

    private void makeMainFrame() {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int height = (int) (screenSize.height * 0.75);
        int width = (int) (screenSize.width * 0.75);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Learning Java Swing");
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    }

    private void makePanels() {
        frame.getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        centerPanel.setOpaque(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Done. I skimmed out a few things that I don't think are relevant.

Comment: Well...your runnable example works for me...

Comment: One issue I would point is the fact that you are calling `setVisible` on the frame before you've actually added anything to it, this can cause issues.  Consider calling only after you have setup the initial UI

Comment: That was it. Wow, I would have never noticed that. Thank you!

Comment: It's always the simple things ;) - See how important runnable examples are ;)

Answer (score 1):

Reusing the same GridBagConstraints object might be a problem. Try always creating new GridBagConstraints  in addComponentToGridbag method